# Showing the type A -> A

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
data A = Num Int
     | Fun (A -> A) String deriving Show

instance Show (Fun (A -> A) String) where
  show (Fun f s) = s
```

I would like to have an attribute for a function `A -> A` to print it, therefore there is a `String` type parameter to `Fun`. When I load this into ghci, I get

```
/home/kmels/tmp/show-abs.hs:4:16:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Fun'
```

I guess this could be achieved by adding a new data type

```
data FunWithAttribute = FA (A -> A) String
```

adding `data A = Num Int | Fun FunWithAttribute` and writing an `instance Show FunWithAttribute`. Is the additional data type avoidable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instances are defined for types as a whole, not individual constructors, which is why it complains about `Fun` not being a type.

I assume your overall goal is to have a `Show` instance for `A`, which can't be derived because functions can't (in general) have a `Show` instance. You have a couple options here:

#### Write your own `Show` instance outright:

That is, something like:

```
instance Show A where
    show (Num n) = "Num " ++ show n
    show (Fun _ s) = s
```

In many cases, this makes the most sense. But sometimes it's nicer to derive `Show`, especially on complex recursive types where only one case of many is not automatically `Show`-able.

#### Make `A` derivable:

You can only derive `Show` for types that contain types that themselves have `Show` instances. There's no instance for `A -> A`, so deriving doesn't work. But you can write one that uses a placeholder of some sort:

```
instance Show (A -> A) where
    show _ = "(A -> A)"
```

Or even just an empty string, if you prefer.

Note that this requires [the `FlexibleInstances` language extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#flexible-instance-head); it's one of the most harmless and commonly used extensions, is supported by multiple Haskell implementations, and the restrictions it relaxes are (in my opinion) a bit silly to begin with, so there's little reason to avoid it.

An alternate approach would be to have a wrapper type, as you mention in the question. You could even make this more generic:

```
data ShowAs a = ShowAs a String

instance Show (ShowAs a) where
    show (ShowAs _ s) = s
```

...and then use `(ShowAs (A -> A))` in the `Fun` constructor. This makes it a bit awkward by forcing you to do extra pattern matching any time you want to use the wrapped type, but it gives you lots of flexibility to "tag" stuff with how it should be displayed, e.g. `` showId = id `ShowAs` "id" `` or suchlike.

Comment: Another option would be `import Text.Show.Functions` for deriving.

Comment: Once you have `instance Show (A->A)` how about an additional `instance Show (B->B)` later?

Comment: @Ingo: Sure, why not? Instances can share the same type constructor if it's applied to distinct monomorphic types.

Comment: I am sure you need some pragma here, since the Haskell 2010 report says: *The type (T u1 . . . uk ) must take the form of a type constructor T applied to simple type
variables u1 , . . . uk ; furthermore, T must not be a type synonym, and the ui must all be distinct.*

Comment: @Ingo: Yes, it requires `FlexibleInstances`. There's a reason why that's one of the most commonly used extensions. The limitation you quote is a bit silly, to my mind.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I just think it would be a good habit to explicitly state the required pragmas when presenting a solution. It's not the least against you or the fact that one uses non-standard solutions. It is just that I have the impression that we currently seem to have lots of beginners, and it may be better not to confuse them more than needed.

Comment: @Ingo: Ah, yes, quite true, that was mostly laziness on my part. I've added it to the answer, but for stuff like that it's often reasonable to simply edit the post yourself.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I wouldn't do that with posts from people like you who know Haskell much better than I do. In addition, I tend to be lazy .... :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I'm not following what you are asking for. But the above code could be written like this in order to compile:

```
data A = Num Int
     | Fun (A -> A) String 

instance Show A where
  show (Fun f s) = s
  show (Num i) = show i
```

#### Some explanation

It looked like you were trying to write a show instance for a constructor (Fun). Class instances are written for the entire data type (there *might* be exceptions, dunno). So you need to write one show matching on each constructor as part of the instance. Num and Fun are each constructors of the data type A.

Also, `deriving` can't be used unless each parameter of each constructor is, in turn, member of, in this case, `Show`. Now, your example is a bit special since it wants to `Show (A -> A)`. How to show a function is somewhat explained in the other responses, although I don't think there is an exhaustive way. The other examples really just "show" the type or some place holder.

Answer (score 4):

A `Show` instance (or any class instance) needs to be defined for a data type, not for a type *constructor*. That is, you need simply

```
instance Show A where
```

Apparently, you're trying to get this instance with the `deriving`, but that doesn't work because Haskell doesn't know how to show `A->A`. Now it seems you don't even *want* to show that function, but `deriving Show` instances always show *all* available information, so you can't use that.

The obvious, and best, solution to your problem is worldsayshi's: don't use `deriving` at all, but define a proper instance yourself. Alternatively, you can define a pseudo-instance for `A->A` and then use deriving:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}

data A = Num Int | Fun (A->A) String   deriving(Show)

instance Show (A->A) where  show _ = ""
```

This works like

```
Prelude> Fun (const $ Num 3) "bla"
Fun  "bla"
```